# Нелицензионный контент и блокировка приложения в Play Market

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

Добрый вечер! Имеется приложение, которое в скором времени выйдет в Play Market. В самом приложении есть возможность загрузки образов дисков (.iso) с установленной системой, что потом используется для запуска системы в приложении. Образ диска может иметь нелицензионную систему из семейства Windows устаревшей версии (с 1.0 по XP).

---

Что происходит при публикации такого приложения? Интересуют конкретно такие вопросы:

1. Проходит ли приложение предварительную проверку, где товарищи из Google скажут мне так не делать и попросят убрать то и то, после чего приложение снова пройдет проверку?
2. Если приложение опубликовалось и товарищи из Microsoft или еще от куда-то возмутятся, что у меня в приложении есть возможность, нарушающая лицензионные права — заблокируется ли аккаунт или приложение?
3. Если в третьем пункте ответ положительны: заблокируется на всегда или до выяснения обстоятельств и удаления функции, которая нарушает лицензионные права?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. <s>Нет. Когда я смотрел в последний раз, премодерации не было.</s> [Видимо, ввели.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709324/181100) Посему, есть шанс, что вместо блокировки вы получите отказ ещё до публикации, но не бан. От этого несколько легче, но пробовать, на мой взгляд, всё равно не стоит.
2. Да. Скорее всего и приложение, и аккаунт.
3. Вторыми шансами они не славятся. Не думаю, что гугл даст шанс это оспорить: если прямое и сознательное нарушение авторского права имело место, обжаловать нечего. Тот факт, что распространение не является прямым назначением приложения и может быть удалено без ощутимого ущерба для основной функциональности, не отменяет самого нарушения.

С похожей проблемой сталкиваются разработчики программных пакетов для эмуляции игровых устройств, и типичное решение на данный момент — нигде (официально, во всяком случае) не распространять образов с ПО, которое у вас нет прав распространять.

---

Пример: [Retropie. Вот что они говорят у себя на сайте на этот счёт](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/First-Installation/#transferring-roms):

> Из-за природы/сложностей законов об авторском праве/интеллектуальной собственности, которые разнятся от страны к стране, ROMы не могут распространяться вместе с RetroPie, пользователь должен достать их сам. У вас должны быть ROMы только игр, которые у вас есть.

И дистрибутив никаких ROM'ов не содержит. Их можно в момент найти в поисковых системах, и на торрент-трекерах есть образы с целыми пачками оных. Но это "серая зона", в которую разработчики в открытую не суются.

---

Некоторые спасаются, прикрывшись размещённой рядом со ссылкой на скачивание фразой вроде "только для ознакомления, мы не распространяем". Даже если юридически это может сработать (т. е. есть шансы отбиться в суде? хотя я не слышал о случаях), это очень ненадёжное решение, которое может дорого обойтись. Но его применяют. Наблюдал на нескольких интернет-радиостанциях в отношении скачивания проигрываемых композиций.

Comment: А если сделать так: убрать ЯВНО эту функцию, но сделать возможным подключения источников для загрузки? То есть пользователь качает с 4PDA файл типа `windows_images.repo`, приложение считывает этот файл и в приложении отображает список систем для загрузки? А файлы распространять через свой сайт или 4PDA?

Comment: @RostislavDugin это серая зона, о которой можно поругаться в суде. До тех пор, пока ваша прямая связь с источником недоказуема, вам сложно что-то предъявить. С другой стороны, с торрентами активно борются как с технологией, несмотря на то, что её часто применяют в совершенно чистых целях, вроде распространения дистров Linux, да и сама технология фундаментально не про пиратство. Она лишь "удобна". Насколько мне известно, торрент-клиенты в Play Market не банят, но лучше не верьте мне на слово и поройтесь в информации сами на этот счёт.

Comment: В само приложение будет вшит источник с бесплатными образами типа Linux, FreeDOS и т.д.. Сейчас решаю вопрос, добавлять ли в этот источник лицензионное ПО... Вот readme проекта, там механизм описан — https://github.com/RostislavDugin/OSLoader/blob/master/readme_ru.md

Comment: Дело действительно может дойти до суда? На большую прибыль я не надеюсь, но судиться из-за маленького приложения...

Comment: @RostislavDugin ну, скажу так, решение блокировать подобное приложение было бы спорным. Если б блокировка состоялась, у вас были бы доводы, чтобы её оспорить, но инициатива идти в суд если (мягенькое такое "если") и будет исходить, то скорее от вас.

Comment: Чем вы рискуете? Возможностью распространять приложения в Play Market в дальнейшем. Фактически, пожизненно. Не только на аккаунт, но и на ваши сопоставимые персональные данные в других аккаунтах тоже. Примерно как тут охотятся за спамом: активно отстреливают аккаунты по разным признакам. Но у гугла, в связи с необходимостью осуществления выплат, информации для этого заметно больше.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Уточнил у Microsoft по поводу старых версий, может Вам будет интересно — https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_install/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0/5f45d44b-c792-4200-a477-8648f553b95c?tm=1503437791937

Answer (score 4):

1. Теперь премодерация есть. В т.ч. и обновлений приложений. Проверял в этом месяце дважды. Можно перестраховаться и для случая с непонятными правами на контент послать в гугл письмо с просьбой убедиться что права у вас есть, чтоб вас не банили внезапно, до выкладывания APK файла. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6320428
2. Да. Скорее всего и приложение, и аккаунт в случае жалобы от мелкомягких. Только приложение, если гугл не уверен в своих действиях.
3. Смотря какие нарушения. У меня были случаи блокировок и удаления приложений с объяснением что у меня нет прав на чужой контент. После подачи аппеляции со словами "вот ссылка где показано, что весь контент свободно распространяется и я имею право его юзать" блокировку приложения откатывали в течении 2-4 часов.

Всё вышеописанное относится к легальному контенту, право на использование которого легко доказать одной ссылкой